# Getting Console error while install Magento CE ver 2.3.1 on win10/XAMPP

Tags: magento

I tried a few times to install on win10/XAMPP Magento CE ver 2.3.1.

It always fails with the following console errors. Any Help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use 127.0.0.0 instead of local host and give permission to var pub generated folder

Comment: Not getting any luck still getting the same error @salim.